# Testing app on iphone that has greater ios version than xcode's sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to iOS Development, and I have a good old macbook that has Mac OS X 10.6.8 - snow leopard. My Xcode version is 3.2 and **iOS 4.3 SDK** works perfectly on it. However I have an iPhone 4 runs on **iOS 6**, and I want to test my app on it. In the project settings I choose iOS 4.3 as base sdk.

Is it possible to test on a device that runs on newer SDK than developed SDK like we have in android? or Should I upgrade my system to Mountain Lion and install iOS 6 SDK ?

Edit: I've already enrolled to developer program

Comment: To get full support for your device you will need to upgrade. Also upgrading will give you so much new stuff like, ARC, [`UIAppearance Proxy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). I don't think you can get Xcode 3.* to recognize iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can test your application on xcode 3.2

Just prepare build, drag your application to iTunes (create .ipa file)-> Sync with your device.

But you cannot debug your application.

Also, as every apps need to have iPhone 5 compatibility, I would suggest you to upgrade your mac to latest Mountain Lion, as it will just cost you 20$ only. In that you can code special for iOS 6 like orientation methods of iOS 5 are no more continued in iOS 6, so its better you update your system.

Hope this info helps you..